# Kernel Panic on El Capitan Mac Book Pro

Tags: kernel-panic

Can anyone look at this crash log and tell me what's causing my kernel panic?  Forgive me if I am breaking some rule, as I'm new to this

```
Tue Nov 22 05:40:34 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 3 caller 0xffffff80075ce6fa): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80075200bc, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x0000000000000040, CR3: 0x00000004371e906a, CR4: 0x00000000001626e0
RAX: 0x0000000000000000, RBX: 0x0000000000000040, RCX: 0x00000000000202d1, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff91f524ba40, RBP: 0xffffff91f524ba70, RSI: 0xffffff8043cfc000, RDI: 0xffffff800b145d80
R8:  0xffffff8028979800, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0xffffff81a65bb098, R11: 0xffffff804c262a00
R12: 0xffffff8025e28400, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0x0000000000001000, R15: 0xffffff800b145d80
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff80075200bc, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000000000040, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x3, PL: 1

Backtrace (CPU 3), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff91f524b6d0 : 0xffffff80074dab52 
0xffffff91f524b750 : 0xffffff80075ce6fa 
0xffffff91f524b930 : 0xffffff80075ec563 
0xffffff91f524b950 : 0xffffff80075200bc 
0xffffff91f524ba70 : 0xffffff800751c8d2 
0xffffff91f524bb50 : 0xffffff80074e4d99 
0xffffff91f524bb70 : 0xffffff7f87f23aef 
0xffffff91f524bbb0 : 0xffffff7f87f2359f 
0xffffff91f524bc60 : 0xffffff8007a173d2 
0xffffff91f524bcc0 : 0xffffff80079f01f4 
0xffffff91f524be30 : 0xffffff80079cd816 
0xffffff91f524be60 : 0xffffff80079c72c7 
0xffffff91f524bf00 : 0xffffff80079c70fe 
0xffffff91f524bf60 : 0xffffff8007a28701 
0xffffff91f524bfb0 : 0xffffff80075ecd66 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.Cvnt.nke(208.7.97)[A3DBF430-2127-390E-8E5A-EF3F6BB84092]@0xffffff7f87f20000->0xffffff7f87f32fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: com.avast.proxy

Mac OS version:
15G1108

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Sep  1 15:01:16 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.11~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FD33DB7B-CF7A-3AD5-AF00-23EA2D35FEFA
Kernel slide:     0x0000000007200000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8007400000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007300000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 395399349253
last loaded kext at 207330939326: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f88595000, size 69632)
loaded kexts:
com.disc-soft.DAEMONTools.VirtualSCSIBus    1.0.2
com.avast.AvastFileShield   3.0.0
com.avast.PacketForwarder   2.1
com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.snowleopard 5.9.1
com.Cvnt.driver.CvntDriver  0208.07.97
com.Cvnt.nke    0208.07.97
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
tc.tctechnologies.driver.PaeFireStudio  4.2.0 39752
com.devguru.driver.SamsungMTP   1.4.32
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4718
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver    3.7.1
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.22.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.macos.driver.AppleUSBEthernetHost 8.0.1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   274.12
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   274.12
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.4
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.9
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    517.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1040.1.1a6
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.4
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   4.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  303.3.1
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWAudio   270.6
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.3
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireAVC   4.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.1.3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.9
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.11
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B0D, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.2f44
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435438473353313630424D2E4D3136464E00
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435438473353313630424D2E4D3136464E00
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.6f1 17910, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
PCI Card: pci11c1,5901, IEEE 1394 Open HCI, Thunderbolt@195,0,0
Serial ATA Device: OWC Mercury EXTREME Pro 6G SSD, 960.2 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS41N
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub
USB Device: USB Uno MIDI Interface
USB Device: OWC Express USB 3.0
USB Device: My Passport 0730
USB Device: USB 2.0 Hub
USB Device: My Passport 07B8
USB Device: My Passport 259D
USB Device: My Passport 07A8
USB Device: MPKmini2
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
FireWire Device: PreSonus FIREPOD, PreSonus, Up to 400 Mb/sec
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
Thunderbolt Device: Thunderbolt to FireWire Adapter, Apple Inc., 1, 5.6
```

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1Iuj8gMfe2GbFExTmpGOWFnT3c/view?usp=sharing

```
Anonymous UUID:       83422E14-132E-18DB-2CA8-E0A3A9AE5210

Tue Nov 22 19:52:04 2016

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff8005720210): "Invalid queue element pointers for 0xffffff803a844000: next 0 prev 0"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.60.11/osfmk/kern/queue.h:241
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff91f38d3920 : 0xffffff80056dab52 
0xffffff91f38d39a0 : 0xffffff8005720210 
0xffffff91f38d39e0 : 0xffffff800571c8d2 
0xffffff91f38d3ac0 : 0xffffff80056e4d99 
0xffffff91f38d3ae0 : 0xffffff7f86123aef 
0xffffff91f38d3b20 : 0xffffff7f8612359f 
0xffffff91f38d3bd0 : 0xffffff8005c173d2 
0xffffff91f38d3c30 : 0xffffff8005bf01f4 
0xffffff91f38d3da0 : 0xffffff8005c02f83 
0xffffff91f38d3e90 : 0xffffff8005bffb8a 
0xffffff91f38d3f60 : 0xffffff8005c28380 
0xffffff91f38d3fb0 : 0xffffff80057eca58 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.Cvnt.nke(208.7.97)[A3DBF430-2127-390E-8E5A-EF3F6BB84092]@0xffffff7f86120000->0xffffff7f86132fff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: wine

Mac OS version:
15G1108

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 15.6.0: Thu Sep  1 15:01:16 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.60.11~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: FD33DB7B-CF7A-3AD5-AF00-23EA2D35FEFA
Kernel slide:     0x0000000005400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8005600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8005500000
System model name: MacBookPro9,2 (Mac-6F01561E16C75D06)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 274766874191
last loaded kext at 147792572472: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.10 (addr 0xffffff7f86795000, size 69632)
loaded kexts:
com.disc-soft.DAEMONTools.VirtualSCSIBus    1.0.2
com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.snowleopard 5.9.1
com.Cvnt.driver.CvntDriver  0208.07.97
com.Cvnt.nke    0208.07.97
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
tc.tctechnologies.driver.PaeFireStudio  4.2.0 39752
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4718
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.22.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.6.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   274.12
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics   10.1.4
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.0.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    208
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.12.9
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri 10.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.13
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBStorageCoexistentDriver    3.7.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  245.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver   245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 245.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  327.6
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    517.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.BootCache 38
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.7.0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    10.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    5.5.4
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   800.20.24
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   1040.1.1a6
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.8
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 218.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   163
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   218.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWAudio   270.6
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 274.12
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    525
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   108.2.3
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder   1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.4.6f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.4.6f1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.12.9
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 274.12
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireAVC   4.2.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.1.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.1.3
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d7
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    205.11
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.12.9
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.14d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   4.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  303.3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   204.4
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 250.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  900.4.1
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    517.50.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.7.7
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1110.26
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.8.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 417.4
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing to look for in any kernel panic is non-Apple kexts.

Google to find out what they are & check with the makers if any update is needed for El Capitan, otherwise uninstall.

The crash seems to be in `com.Cvnt.nke` which Google tells me is [Covenant Eyes](http://www.covenanteyes.com) but other suspect kexts are

```
com.disc-soft.DAEMONTools.VirtualSCSIBus    1.0.2
com.paceap.kext.pacesupport.snowleopard 5.9.1
com.Cvnt.driver.CvntDriver  0208.07.97
com.Cvnt.nke    0208.07.97
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    2
tc.tctechnologies.driver.PaeFireStudio  4.2.0 39752
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   4718
```

Soundflower is definitely suspect & has been causing crashes since about Mavericks. There's a relatively recent beta with code signing at https://github.com/mattingalls/Soundflower/releases/
Better still, lose it if you can afford to live without it.

Similarly, your PACE iLok software is badly out of date - https://www.paceap.com

TC Electronics at http://www.tcelectronic.com

Little Snitch can be updated at https://www.obdev.at/index.html

Daemontools - http://www.disc-soft.com

Also check for updates to Avast - or lose it & find better if not faster antivirus, see [AV-TEST.org](https://www.av-test.org/en/news/news-single-view/12-security-suites-for-mac-os-x-put-to-the-test/)